# Host Nodejs app in IIS server

Tags: node.js, express, iis-7, web-config, iisnode

I have hosted a NodeJs express app on IIS server using iisnode. App is running on node server without giving any error. it gives me following error with iisnode.
Used Express version is 4.13.4.

[image]

I have installed URL rewrite module for IIS.

My server.js file as follows.

```
'use strict';

// Module dependencies.
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = module.exports = exports.app = express();

app.locals.siteName = "IOS IBE";
app.use(cors());
//cors and preflight filtering
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
//preflight needs to return exact request-header
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method)
        return res.send(204);
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Start server
var port = 4015;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Distributor portal App manager server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.get('env'));
});
```

My web.conf is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>         
      <handlers>
           <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
     </handlers>
      <rewrite>
           <rules>

                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="StaticContent">
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                     <conditions>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                </rule>

           </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: can you show us your proxy configuration in IIS ARR?

Comment: I added my web.conf too. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Oh... Its a litte different to what I imagined let me check the docs. 
Did you follow: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx ?

Comment: Yes I did. Sample apps are running well in my server without giving any issue.

Comment: @JanithWidarshana Use process.env.PORT instead of port (4015)

Comment: @JanithWidarshana   Since IIS controls the base address for all HTTP listeners, a node.js application must use the listen address provided by the iisnode module through the process.env.PORT environment variable rather than specify its own.

Comment: @Apoorv it works for me. Better if you can post a Answer.